# Heap-Allocated QApplication Getting Deleted

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, segmentation-fault

In a basic C++ Qt Widgets application, creating a `QApplication` on the stack or heap-allocating it directly in the `main` function works, but calling a function the heap-allocates a `QApplication` and using the returned pointer gives a segmentation fault:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

QApplication* create_application(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return new QApplication(argc, argv);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication* app = create_application(argc, argv);
    QWidget window;
    window.show();
    app->exec();
}
```

I think it's being automatically delete, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Have you run it through a debugger and looked at the stack trace?

Comment: It's not getting deleted, that's impossible. However, I get the same strange behavior. Some weird bug is happening... somewhere :-/ It happens also without heap allocation: `QApplication create_application(int argc, char* argv[]) { return QApplication(argc, argv); }` (This requires C++17, so `CONFIG += c++17`.)

Comment: @NikosC. it's because `QApplication` takes `argc` as a reference and requires the reference to stay valid through the lifetime of the instance of `QApplication`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not that you create your `QApplication` with dynamic storage duration, but that the constructor of `QApplication` is [`QApplication::QApplication(int &argc, char **argv)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication) taking `argc` as reference.

And these two notes/warnings:

> Note: `argc` and `argv` might be changed as Qt removes command line arguments that it recognizes.

> Warning: **The data referred to by `argc` and `argv` must stay valid for the entire lifetime of the QApplication object**. In addition, `argc` must be greater than zero and `argv` must contain at least one valid character string.

The reference to the `argc` parameter in your `create_application` becomes invalid after you exit that function, which violates that warning.

If you change `QApplication* create_application(int argc, char* argv[])` to `QApplication* create_application(int &argc, char* argv[])` it will work, as `argc` now referes to the `argc` parameter of `main` and is not a copy of it.

Comment: But whether `argc` is changed shouldn't matter, since it is not used again anyway?

Comment: @NgocMinhNguyen If calling `exec` will access/modify `argc` (which those two note/warning indicate) then the instance of `QApplication` will use a dangling reference to the parameter of `create_application` that does not exist anymore at that point of time. Resulting in undefined behavior (which most likely corrupts elements on the stack).

Comment: Ok this is true, since `argc` is stored as a reference. https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qcoreapplication_p.h.html#QCoreApplicationPrivate::argc

Comment: @NgocMinhNguyen The important part is the warning in the documentation that tells you that those must stay valid (even if there would be no indication in the source code).

Comment: If the constructor expects a reference, is there any way to use it in another language with FFI and a C wrapper?

Comment: @programmer you want to create the QApplication in C++ but invoke the creation through FFI?

Comment: @t.niese I want to make `extern "C"` functions that wrap the constructor and some methods of `QApplication` so I can use it in other languages with FFI.

Comment: @programmer And the instance `QApplication` should continue to exist after that function call that constructs this instance? Anyhow this is a new question and should be asked as a new one.